# Trying to convert year quarter 2Q03 format column values to date in Power Bi

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I am a newbie to power BI and trying to convert Year Quarter column which is in `2Q03` to either `30/06/2003 or 2003 Q2`. Much appreciated for the help in advacne.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latter format is a bit easier. You can use `Text.Start` and `Text.End` in a custom column to achieve this:

```
"20" & Text.End([String], 2) & " Q" & Text.Start([String], 1)
```

This takes the right two characters as the year and the left one as the quarter.

---

For the former format, similar logic, but you use `#date(yyyy,mm,dd)` instead of joining strings:

```
Date.EndOfQuarter(
    #date(
       2000 + Number.From(Text.End([String], 2)),
       3 * Number.From(Text.Start([String], 1)),
       1)))
```